# copy windowsform chart to clipboard VB

Tags: vb.net, charts

I need to copy a chart (System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart) to clipboard in order to paste it in other application. I use below code but it gives error on the last line for "img" says "Value of Type Bitmap cannot be converted to Bitmapsource"

Any help to rectify the error is highly appreciated.

```
Private Sub CopyChartBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles CopyChartBtn.Click

    Dim main = DirectCast(Application.Current.MainWindow, MainWindow)
    Dim SET_H = DirectCast(main.Frame1.Content, SET_Home)
    Dim chart1 = DirectCast(SET_H.Benchchart.Child, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart)

    'save image
    Dim img As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(chart1.Width, chart1.Height)
    Dim gr As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(img)
    chart1.Printing.PrintPaint(gr, New System.Drawing.Rectangle(System.Drawing.Point.Empty, chart1.Size))
    Clipboard.SetImage(img)

End Sub
```

My project is WPF and I am hosting windowsform chart in it. Maybe that is the problem because when I run it in a windows form project it works fine

Comment: ur code works good , check the .net framework version of your project

Comment: @snoopcommands I am using .net 4.5.2

Comment: i checked it and it worked very good , your code copied the chart and i could paste it to mspaint , check your imported namespaces then. I did nothing created a new project , put a chart and pasted your code there.

Comment: I checked the internet and i see that other people also are using it, but I got that error.

Comment: My project is WPF and I am hosting windowsform chart in it. Maybe that is the problem because when I run it in a windows form project it works fine.

Comment: then you should copy chart image to a bitmapsource ,  it seems on WPF clipboard.setimage requires bitmapsource.

Comment: @snoopcommands How to make it? can you help please

Comment: I actually figured it out in other way, I used System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetImage(img) and it works.Originally it considers  System.Windows.Clipboard.SetImage(img) when not using the namespace, yet, if you guide on the codes to create bitmapsource would be appreciated.

Comment: i dont know too much WPF sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetImage(img) and it works.Originally when it is a WPF project it uses System.Windows.Clipboard.SetImage(img) when not using the namespace